# MySQL - ORDER BY SUM does not sort when using derived table

Tags: mysql, sorting, sum, sql-order-by

I have two identical tables: money_stat_buy and money_stat_buy_tmp (I dropped some columns for simplicity):

```
id          int(11) AI PK
artikul_id  int(11)
n           int(11)
```

I want to get the sum of column `n` group by `artikul_id` FROM both tables. I used a query with a UNION statement.

I get right results but the sorting by sum does not work.

```
SELECT artikul_id, SUM(cnt)
FROM 
 (   SELECT artikul_id, SUM(n) as cnt
     FROM mhouse_diff.money_stat_buy table1
     GROUP BY artikul_id

     UNION ALL 

     SELECT artikul_id, SUM(n) as cnt
     FROM mhouse_diff.money_stat_buy_tmp table2
     GROUP BY artikul_id
 ) 
table_derived  
GROUP BY artikul_id
ORDER BY SUM(cnt) DESC;

+------------+----------+
| artikul_id | SUM(cnt) |
+------------+----------+
|       6793 |        6 |
|      16516 |       15 |
|      12212 |       10 |
|       7805 |        3 |
|       8750 |        1 |
...
```

I managed to solve this problem by removing `GROUP BY` statements from the inner queries and selecting `n` instead of `SUM(n)`:

```
SELECT artikul_id, SUM(cnt)
FROM 
 (   SELECT artikul_id, n as cnt
     FROM mhouse_diff.money_stat_buy table1

     UNION ALL 

     SELECT artikul_id, n as cnt
     FROM mhouse_diff.money_stat_buy_tmp table2
 ) 
table_derived  
GROUP BY artikul_id
ORDER BY SUM(cnt) DESC;

+------------+----------+
| artikul_id | SUM(cnt) |
+------------+----------+
|       5654 |     2062 |
|      17522 |     2006 |
|      17979 |      190 |
|       8052 |       90 |
 ...
```

But I wonder why the first query does not sort the results. Is there some mistake???

Moreover - the first query works well on my local machine (sorts just like it is supposed to) BUT does not work (does not sort) in production environment.

Local mysql version:
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.46, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.3

Production environment mysql version:
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.40-36.1, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

P.S. `UNION` statement is not even necessary here - the following query does not sort either:

```
SELECT artikul_id, SUM(cnt)
FROM 
 (   SELECT artikul_id, SUM(n) as cnt
     FROM mhouse_diff.money_stat_buy table1
     GROUP BY artikul_id
 ) 
table_derived  
GROUP BY artikul_id
ORDER BY SUM(cnt) DESC;
```

Comment: MIght be a mysql bug,but it`s just a guess

Comment: if you are taking the pain to make `cnt` an alias on the inner, why not use it on the outer. Just gives mysql something else to drop an egg on. That said, I am not getting your results, see [Pastie](http://pastie.org/10547376)

Comment: no wait, you are, nevermind. Sorry, I think I need a coffee

Comment: on your last chunk from the edit, even though it is a curious question, `table_derived` is already resolved with what your outer wrapper is doing anyway with the aggregate part. The only thing the outer is doing is an `order by` to improve on the lot. But you are forcing it thru another aggregation (albeit I would expect the answer to be the same)

Comment: @Drew - you are right - the outer query is just supposed to improve the lot by `ORDER BY`, so I don't know what the problem is. Seems to me like MySQL bug.

Comment: seems horrifying frankly

Comment: @sergei are you sure its doing that? what version of mysql are you running. I just tested this exact thing and it works for me.

Comment: @sergei, very interesting issue. I tested this on MySQL 5.1 & MySQL 5.6 both returned the results ordered correctly. Is there something unusual about your set up?

Comment: @SteveE. I did the same and got ordered results. Not sure what the issue is.

Comment: @johnruddell - Yes, I am positive. I killed about three hours trying to understand why. I can provide a video if you want )) 
There is nothing unusual in my setup - not that I know of.
And it works in my local environment but fails to work either in our test environment or production environment:

test:

`mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.40-36.1, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper`

production:

`mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.41-37.0, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper`

Comment: Screenshot: [link](http://s12.postimg.org/8h2kgdh6l/sort_not_working.png)

Comment: Also - explain asserts `Using filesort` on derived table:
[link](http://s1.postimg.org/bp6y0yr8f/explain.png)

Comment: ok so the first thing you need to do is check and make sure your local environment is exactly the same as your production one. Make sure your mysql config is the same and that its the same version and everything. if I test on [**sqlfiddle.com**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9da2e/3) it works fine